# Integrating Kendo.Grid with Backbone.Collection

Tags: backbone.js, kendo-ui

### Background

I'm working in a client-server REST based application which manages various kinds of information and defines a generic `EntitiesCollection` which extends `Backbone.Collection`.
The `EntitiesCollection` has an API (it extends the Backbone.Collection API) for CRUD operations, filtering, sorting and so on.

My team needs to write a Grid component which can display and manipulate an `EntitiesCollection` object. This grid will be based on some 3rd party component and we are seriously considering using `Kendo.Grid`.

### The Challange

My first question is whether anyone ever tried to **use Kendo.Grid whose data\data-source is actually a Backbone.Collection** and whether that is a good and applicable idea at all?

I have seen various articles regarding **Kendo** and **Backbone** integration including Derick Bailey's [Backbone And Kendo UI: A Beautiful Combination](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-11-26/backbone_and_kendo_ui_a_beautiful_combination.aspx). However, these articles talk about view level integration (wrapping the `Kendo.Grid` with a `Backbone.View`). What I am looking for is data level integration - making `Kendo.Grid` work with `Backbone.Collection`.

### Options

As far as I understand so far `Kendo.Grid` works with a `Kendo.DataSource` which in turn holds an internal collection - a `Kendo.ObservableArray`.

Assuming we are going for it I see several implementation options:

1. One of the options we discussed is converting our `EntitiesCollection` to a `Kendo.DataSource` however this seems to be a non option - the communication with the server has to be done through our own objects.
2. Replace the `Kendo.DataSource` with the `EntitiesCollection` - our `EntitiesCollection` will implement the `Kendo.DataSource` API and the grid will work with it as its dataSource object. I don't like this solution since I think I will loose a lot of the functionality that Kendo gives me in the `Kendo.DataSource` object.
3. The `Kendo.DataSource` will wrap our own `EntitiesCollection` and delegate requests to it.
4. The `Kendo.ObservableArray` object contained by the `Kendo.DataSource` will wrap our `EntitiesCollection` (see [this](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-backbone) sample implementation I found online). This approach seem to work with simple use cases however something seems wrong to me - I think that the `Backbone.Collection` is not the `data` object (in Kendo terminology) but the `DataSource` object - since it is the one that interacts with the remote server and fetches the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in this article that I just posted:

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-02-07/wrapping_a_backbone_collection_in_a_kendo_data_datasource.aspx

In it, I walk through the basics of what it takes to build an adapter to use a Backbone.Collection as the backing store for a DataSource, and connect it to a Kendo UI Grid.

I haven't completely solved all of your needs - for example, no paging support - but hopefully this will get you down the path far enough.

Answer (score 1):

All Kendo UI widgets (grid including) can bind **only** to an instance of the `kendo.data.DataSource`.

I created the '[kendo-backbone](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-backbone)' project to show a possible way to integrate Kendo UI with Backbone. The project wraps an existing Backbone Collection as a Kendo ObservableArray. The latter acts like a simple proxy and works entirely with the Backbone collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In my post I referred to your project in github (see option #4). My concern regarding this kind of solution is that a `Backbone.Collection` is more a DataSource object than a collection of items since it is the object that performs the communication with the server (just like the `Kendo.DataSource`).
Why did you decide to wrap the `Backbone.Collection` with `ObservableArray` and not the `Kendo.DataSource`?
How did you mean for features such as paging and sorting to work with this kind of integration?

Comment: Because as I said Kendo UI widgets cannot bind to a Backbone Collection. This is why I wrapped the latter to something which Kendo Widgets know and can work with. You can still sync your Backbone collection as you wish.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What about paging? You either use the Kendo DataSource paging or implement paging using your Backbone collection. If you pick the latter configure the Kendo DataSource for serverPaging and use the paging info to pass it to the Backbone collection.

Comment: Let's take paging for example. I would like to implement paging in the server and I would like my `Backbone.Collection` to fetch the next page.
How would you make that work?

1. If I configure 'serverPaging = false' this will obviously not work since the `Kendo.Query` object will search for items that do not exist in the collection.
2. If I configure 'serverPaging = true' then the `DataSource` will try to fetch the data by itself and through my `Backbone.Collection`.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something here? I would really appreciate your detailed answer on this -> how does a page flow supposed to work? (in case the paging is done on the server side).

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how Backbone is supposed to do paging. I recommend asking a new question.